# JList reserving memory for data

Tags: java, arrays, memory, memory-management

I am making two JLists. The first is a list of items that can be chosen to transfer to the other list on the event of a buttonclick. One list is given a string of data such as JList(data), the other is an empty declaration of a new JList() object.

```
list1 = new JList<String>(data);
list2 = new JList<String>();
```

How can I reserve the same amount of memory for list 2 as there is being allocated for list 1?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing.  A JList is just a view of something else.  And for a `JList` created using `new JList()`, it is a view of a *read-only empty model*.

Therefore, reserving memory given your code for creating `list2` makes no sense.

If you want `list2` to update in your UI, then you need to instantiate `list2` with a `ListModel`.  Any considerations of reserving space are for the implementation of the `ListModel` that you chose and the way you create it.

However, in the big picture, preallocation is likely to be irrelevant.  If the list is relatively small, the cost of growing the model will be "noise".  If the list is large enough to be significant, then:

1. the CPU / memory used by the list elements is likely to swamp the list overheads
2. other CPU overheads associated with the view (e.g. listener callbacks) may make the UI sluggish, and
3. the (human) UI ergonomics will be problematic.